# oracle12c,sql,difference between count(*) and sum()

Tags: sql, count, sum, oracle12c

Tell me the difference between sql1 and sql2:

sql1:

```
select count(1)
from table_1 a
inner join table_2 b on a.key = b.key where a.id in (
  select id from table_1 group by id having count(1) > 1
)
```

sql2:

```
select sum(a) from (
  select count(1) as a
  from table_1 a
  inner join table_2 b on a.key = b.key group by a.id having count(1) > 1
)
```

Why is the output not the same?

Comment: Unrelated, but: it's a completely unfounded myth, that `count(1)` is faster than `count(*)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queries are not even similar. They are very different. Let's check the first one:

```
select count(1)
from table_1 a
inner join table_2 b
on a.key = b.key 
where a.id in (
  select id from table_1 group by id having count(1) > 1
) ;
```

You are first making an inner join:

```
select count(1) 
from table_1 a 
inner join table_2 b 
on a.key = b.key
```

In this case, you can use count(1), count(id), count(*), it's equivalent. You are counting the **common elements** in both tables: those ones that have in common the key field.

After that, you are enforcing this:

```
where a.id in (
      select id from table_1 group by id having count(1) > 1
    )
```

In other words, that every "id" of the table_1 must be at least two times in the table_1 table.

And lastly, you are doing this:

```
select count(1)
```

In other words, counting those elements. So, translated into english you have done this:

1. get every record of table_1 and pair with records of table_2 for the id, and get only those that match
2. for the result above, filter out only the elements whose id of the table_1 appears more than one time
3. count that result

Let's see what happens with the second query:

```
select sum(a) from (
  select count(1) as a
  from table_1 a
  inner join table_2 b 
  on a.key = b.key 
  group by a.id 
  having count(1) > 1
);
```

You are making the same inner join:

```
  select count(1) as a
  from table_1 a
  inner join table_2 b 
  on a.key = b.key
```

but, you are grouping it by the id of the table:

```
  group by a.id
```

and then filtering out only those elements who appear more than one time:

```
  having count(1) > 1
```

The result so far are a set of records that have in common the key field in both tables, but grouped by the id: this means that **only those fields that are at leas two times in the table_b are outputed of this join**. After that, you group by id, collapsing those results into the table_1.id field and counting the result. I presume that very few records will match this strict criteria.

And lastly, you sum all those set.

Comment: You are right,in fact i miss a  where condition,sql1 [select count(1)
from .... b.sts = '1' where a.id in (
  select id from table_1 group by id having count(1) > 1
)]<-------->sql2[select sum(a) from (
  ......  and b.sts = '1' group by a.id having count(1) > 1
)],as the result,the sql 2 output is much less than sql1, 
etc. 
table_1([key:1,id:XXX1],[key:2,id:XXX1],table_2:([key:1,sts:0],[key:2,sts'1'],
the sql1's output is 1,the sql2'output is 0,for the reason the sql2 
first execute 'and b.sts = '1' ',next excute 'count(1) >1',any way ,it's two different sql.thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

When you use count(*) you count ALL the rows. The SUM() function is an aggregate function that returns the sum of all or distinct values in a set of values.

Comment: you mean the output of sql 2:'''select sum(a) from (
  select count(1) as a
  from table_1 a
  inner join table_2 b on a.key = b.key group by a.id having count(1) =1
)''' is 1